# "travel as countable noun" vs. "journey"

Tags: difference

First: Not part of my question are sentences like:

> Travel by air nowadays is cheaper than before.

I know, that in sentences like this we use travel, because here "travel" is uncountable and used in a general sense. I read in a lot of dictionaries, that we use "travel" in this case. So I was sure, that I have now completely understand when I can use "travel" and when not.

But in my English course I came across example sentences like the following ones. (These must be correct, otherwise they would not have occurred in the course):

> 1)  The travel was too dangerous to take it on my own.

-> Here travel is not general. "Travel" here refers to a concrete journey, that is in the mind of the speaker.
-> Here travel is not uncountable.
-> Before of the discovery of this sentence in my course I would have used "journey" in this sentence.

> 2)  Her second travel around the world took her more than four years.

-> Here travel is not general. "Travel" here refers to a concrete journey, that is in the mind of the speaker.
-> Here travel is not uncountable.
-> Before of the discovery of this sentence in my course I would have used "journey" in this sentence. Or "tour" because several places were visited.

> 3)  I need a really sturdy suitcase for my travel around the world.

-> Here travel is not general. "Travel" here refers to a concrete journey, that is in the mind of the speaker.
-> Here travel is not uncountable.
-> Before of the discovery of this sentence in my course I would have used "journey" in this sentence. Or "tour" because several places were visited.

So I am totally confused now.
Is both OK. Travel and journey? If yes: Would there be a slight difference in the meaning?

Comment: *Her second travel around the world took her more than four years* is not idiomatic English. You can validly use the plural in such contexts *(Her **travels** around the world took her more than four years)* - but not singular, which would need to be converted to ***journey, trip, voyage*** or similar.

Comment: None of those look idiomatic to me.

Comment: So this means it is nevertheless an error in the English online course I guess?